# Prove a random vector is Gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be independent random variables with normal distribution $N(0,\sigma_i^2),$ $i = 1,2,\ldots,n $. Prove the random vector $Y = (X_1, X_1 + X_2,..,X_1+X_2+...X_n)$ is Gaussian and find its distribution.

I'm trying to write $Y = (X_1, X_1 + X_2,\ldots, X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n)$ as a product of a Matrix and a random vector but I'm not sure if this approach is right or not.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Write $Y = AX$ for a suitable matrix $A$, then use properties of the multivariate normal distribution to get the distribution of $Y$.

Answer (score 6):

Although I think you got the answer from the comments, let me expand a bit just for future reference.

We see that $Y = (X_1,X_1+X_2,\ldots,X_1+\cdots+X_n)$ is related to $X = (X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ by the linear relation $Y = AX$ for some suitable $n\times n$ matrix $A$.

Then the desired result follows by noting that the multivariate normal distribution is closed under linear transformations, i.e. if $X\sim N_n(\mu, \Sigma)$, then for any $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and $m\times 1$ vector $a$ (all with real elements), it follows that

$$Y = a+AX\sim N_m(A\mu + a, A\Sigma A^\top).$$